# Unicode characters missing only in Emacs

Tags: init-file, fonts, unicode, customization

A few unicode characters are missing from my Emacs (GNU Emacs 28.2 on macOS 11.6.8.).

They are displayed everywhere else on my system just fine, but in Emacs they look like this:

[image] (Same character in TextEdit: [image])

Strangely enough, other similar characters such as `↫` are working.

This happens with `emacs -Q` as well as all the settings I've tried so far:

```
(set-fontset-font t 'unicode "Apple Color Emoji")
(set-frame-font "Victor Mono-14" nil t)
```

And:

```
(set-fontset-font t 'emoji "Apple Color Emoji")
(set-fontset-font t 'symbol "Symbola")
(set-frame-font "Victor Mono-14" nil t)
```

Comment: Does the font you're using in Emacs display the char as you like when you use that font outside Emacs? If not, change the font you're using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(don't do `set-fontset-font` for the whole unicode range, it will slow down font lookup)

You need to find which specific font has a glyph for that codepoint, which is part of the "bamum" script. On my system that happens to be "Noto Sans Bamum", so the following works for me:

```
(set-fontset-font t 'bamum '("Noto Sans Bamum" . "iso10646-1") nil 'prepend)
```

(I found out which font to use by cheating: I pasted the character into a Word document and used the font that Word chose)

Comment: According to Unicode, that codepoint is not displayed as emoji by default, it needs to be followed by VS-16. You could try using Apple Color Emoji for the 'symbol script as well as using Symbola to change that